# I need to change a value in a table from a web site and remain after refresh , only for my PC

Tags: javascript, html, tampermonkey

I try to do somthing with tempermonkey but I don't know if is ok because I get an error , can you light me guys?
My tempermonkey script until now. I don't know if is correct.

```
var table = document.getElementById('ct10_content_DGdiscipline');
var tbody = table.getElementByTagName('tbody')[1];
var tr = tbody.getElementByTagName('tr')[3];
var td = tr.getElementByTagName('td')[2];
td.textContent = 55;
```

```html
<table id="ctl0_content_DGdiscipline" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="1">
<thead><tr style="background-color:black;color:white;">
<th>Nr<br>Crt</th>
<th>Departament</th>
<th>Nota</th>
<th>Data</th>
<th>PC</th>
<th>Tip</th>
<th>S</th>
<th>Plătit</th>
</tr></thead>
<tbody><tr style="background-color:#D8E0FF;color:black;">
<td align="center" style="border-top:1px solid #000;">
            <span class="gri mic"></span>
          </td>
<td colspan="7" style="border-top:1px solid #000;width:180px;"><div align="center" class="mediu" style="margin:7px 0 7px 0;"><div class="b mare">Data</div>

</tr><tr style="background-color:#E6ECFF;color:black;">
<td align="center">
           1 <span class="gri mic">210134</span>
          </td>
<td style="width:180px;">Convertoare electromecanice</td>
<td align="right" style="white-space:nowrap;width:39px;font-weight:bold;">
          12
          </td>
<td align="center">
          10.02.17
          </td>
<td align="center">8</td>
<td align="center">O</td>
<td align="center">1</td>
<td align="center">
          
          </td>
</tr><tr style="background-color:#D8E0FF;color:black;">
<td align="center">
           2 <span class="gri mic">210135</span>
          </td>
<td style="width:180px;">Managementul proiectelor</td>
<td align="right" style="white-space:nowrap;width:39px;font-weight:bold;">
          5
          </td>
<td align="center">
          19.01.17
          </td>
<td align="center">2</td>
<td align="center">O</td>
<td align="center">1</td>
<td align="center">
```

If I try the Teamper monkey script , I get an error like

ERROR: Execution of script 'New Userscript' failed! Cannot read property 'getElementByTagName' of null

and I don't get it if I do something wrong in a code or all the script is wrong , I don't have too much knowledge in this program if someone here can help me, this will be great

Comment: Try `getElementsByTagName` (plural - the `s` is important)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
var table = document.getElementById('ct10_content_DGdiscipline');
```

try using

```
var table = document.getElementsByTagName("table")[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are new to the field. So here is the deal:

Indexing in language programming starts from zero. So start from 0 not 1.
You are misspelling most of the commands. Compare the following lines with yours:

```
var table = document.getElementById('ctl0_content_DGdiscipline'); 
var tbody = table.getElementsByTagName('tbody')[0]; 
var tr = tbody.getElementsByTagName('tr')[2]; 
var td = tr.getElementsByTagName('td')[0]; 
td.innerHTML = 55;
```

P.S: I didn't know which you wanted to update. So I am considering you wanna update your the first column of the last row.